# How do I get this output?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have got a very large `Pandas Data Frame`. A part of which looks like this:

```
 Rule_Name Rule_Seq_No  Condition Expression  Type   

Rule P     1            ID         19909       Action      
Rule P     1            Type       A           Condition   
Rule P     1            System     B           Condition   
Rule P     2            ID         19608       Action      
Rule P     2            Type       A           Condition  
Rule P     2            System     C           Condition   
Rule S     1            ID         19909       Action      
Rule S     1            Type       A           Condition   
Rule S     1            System     M           Condition   
Rule S     2            ID         19608       Action     
Rule S     2            Type       C           Condition   
Rule S     2            System     F           Condition
```

This table contains some rules with sequence numbers.

I tried using different functions such as `MERGE`, `GROUP BY`, `APPLY` but I am not getting the desired output.

The expected output should be something like this:

```
 Rule_Name  Rule_Seq_No        Condition          Action  

Rule P       1            (Type=A)and(System=B)    19909   
Rule P       2            (Type=A)and(System=C)    19608   
Rule S       1            (Type=A)and(System=M)    19909   
Rule S       2            (Type=A)and(System=F)    19608
```

For the same rule and the same sequence number and where the `TYPE` is `Condition`, I want to merge the rows. And, where the `TYPE` is `ACTION`, it should show in a separate column.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
df1 = (df.assign(Condition = '(' + df['Condition'] + '=' + df['Expression'] + ')')
         .groupby(['Rule_Name','Rule_Seq_No','Type'])
         .agg({'Condition': 'and'.join, 'Expression':'first'})
         .unstack()
         .drop([('Condition','Action'), ('Expression','Condition')], axis=1)
         .droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
  Rule_Name  Rule_Seq_No              Condition Action
0    Rule P            1  (Type=A)and(System=B)  19909
1    Rule P            2  (Type=A)and(System=C)  19608
2    Rule S            1  (Type=A)and(System=M)  19909
3    Rule S            2  (Type=C)and(System=F)  19608
```

**Explanation**:

1. Join columns `Condition`  and `Expression` with `=` and add `()`
2. Aggreagate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join` and `first`
3. Reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)
4. Remove unnecessary columns by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with tuples, because `MultiIndex`
5. Remove top level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html)
6. Data cleaning by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

EDIT:

Solution for oldier pandas versions (below 0.24+) with [`Index.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.droplevel.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(Condition = '(' + df['Condition'] + '=' + df['Expression'] + ')')
         .groupby(['Rule_Name','Rule_Seq_No','Type'])
         .agg({'Condition': 'and'.join, 'Expression':'first'})
         .unstack()
         .drop([('Condition','Action'), ('Expression','Condition')], axis=1))

df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(level=0)
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Rule_Name  Rule_Seq_No              Condition Action
0    Rule P            1  (Type=A)and(System=B)  19909
1    Rule P            2  (Type=A)and(System=C)  19608
2    Rule S            1  (Type=A)and(System=M)  19909
3    Rule S            2  (Type=C)and(System=F)  19608
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'